# mysql not updating php form

Tags: php, mysql, post, sql-update

I have a database with content.

I have a page that displays a table of all records. You can click edit for any record you wish, when you click edit it redirects you to a new form and populates all the information into some form feilds.

When you edit the form values and click submit it is supposed to update the record in the database.

I get a success message when I update,but the record doesnt actually update.

**form.php:**

```
    <?php
            $emp_id= ($_GET["id"]);


              $sql =    "SELECT * FROM people
                        WHERE id='$emp_id' LIMIT 1";
              $result = mysql_query($sql);
              $row_people = mysql_fetch_array($result);
             ?>

              <form method="post" action="update.php?id=<?php echo "$emp_id" ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$row_people[id]"; ?>">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend><b>Name</b></legend>
                        First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row_people[first_name]"; ?>">
                        Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row_people[last_name]"; ?>">
                </fieldset>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="ogs"; // Database name
$tbl_name="people"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$emp_id= ($_GET["id"]);
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name' WHERE id='$emp_id' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Not sure what I am missing.

If i change the $first_name in my query to actual text, it updates fine.

So I'm assuming something is wrong with my form.php or the $_POST?

Comment: your method is post you used get

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_GET` and `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Comment: If my name is Bob O'Doull, what happens to your query? Or maybe my name should be [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Aside from the potential SQL injection problems and the fact the `mysql_` functions are being deprecated (you should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` (which also helps with the injection issues), have you checked to see if there are contents in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the concern. I plan on going back and properly guarding against injection. For now this is all on my local machine and is just me trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `$row_people[first_name]` to `$row_people['first_name']` in `Form.php` file. The same for `id` and `last_name` field also.

```
<?php
$emp_id= ($_GET["id"]);
$id = 0; $firstName = ''; $lastName = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people
        WHERE id='$emp_id' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row_people = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!empty($row_people)) {
    $id = $row_people['id'];
    $firstName = $row_people['first_name'];
    $lastName = $row_people['last_name'];
}
?>

<form method="post" action="update.php?id=<?php echo "$emp_id" ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Name</b></legend>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>">
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name" size="40" value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I get an error if I do that: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\OGS\mods\people\employees\edit_form.php on line 50

Comment: that gets rid of the error, but now im back to where I was before. (The new values are not being updated into the database table.)

Comment: check the `$emp_id` value - should you change to `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in `update.php` file. This value might be empty.

Comment: what value is coming for `$emp_id`.

Comment: Definitely something wrong in my update.php. If i change: $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET first_name='$first_name' to $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET first_name='Nicholas' it works fine.

Comment: the value for $emp_id is 21 (as per the url, which is the correct id in the databse)